# How to tell ElasticSearch to create nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm putting data in ES and check the mapping which is created,

I'm executing this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/testnested2/type1/0' -d '{
  "p1": ["1","2","3","4"], 
   "users" : {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Sm11ith" 
   }
}'
```

and this is the schema it created:

```
{
  "testnested2":{
     "mappings":{
       "type1":{
          "properties":{
            "p1":{"type":"string"},
            "users":{
              "properties":{
                 "first":{"type":"string"},
                 "last":{"type":"string"}
               }
            }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to tell it that "users" is nested or I have to create the mapping for myself.

I would like that ES could create an shema like this:

```
   curl -XPOST http://180.5.5.93:9200/testnested3 -d '{
        "settings" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1
        },
        "mappings" : {  
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "propiedad1" : { "type" : "string"},
                "users" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "include_in_parent": true,
                    "properties": {
                        "first" : {"type": "string" },
                        "last"  : {"type": "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }'
```

Comment: "first" and "last" are nested under "users" - is this what you want? if not can you post an example of what you want?

Comment: I editeded, really, I could do it for myself, it's not too much, I'm just curious about the possible to automatize this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the dynamic mapping feature of ElasticSearch will map `users` as an `object` instead of `nested`.

If you want to tune this behavior, you have to define explicitely a `users` attribute as `nested` either in :

- the type1 mapping
- the *default* mapping of your index. This way, for any type created, the `users` attribute will be set automatically to `nested`(see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html#mapping-dynamic-mapping) for default mapping information)